# Filtering results When date is max

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can anyone advise on what im doing wrong here?

I am trying to select a table full of results, some are duplicates, but the timestamp is different, so I want to filter out by the latest date.

I'm using the following sql query but it just keeps throwing up errors?

```
$sql = "(SELECT  *
FROM    measrate
WHERE TRANS_TIME = (SELECT MAX(TRANS_TIME) FROM measrate)";
```

Comment: Does the sub-select run OK on its own?

Comment: what errors are you getting ?

Comment: Try `$sql = "(SELECT  *
FROM    measrate
WHERE TRANS_TIME = (SELECT MAX(TRANS_TIME) FROM measrate))";` missing `)` added

Comment: @Manwal Thanks it worked, but it seems to have litrally given me the max date of the full set, so I  got one result out of about 1000 results, I just need to filter out the duplicates, Am i doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql = "(SELECT  * FROM    measrate WHERE TRANS_TIME = (SELECT MAX(TRANS_TIME) FROM measrate))";
```

Forgot last bracket

Answer (score 2):

First, the initial parenthesis should be unnecessary:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM measrate m
WHERE TRANS_TIME = (SELECT MAX(TRANS_TIME) FROM measrate m2);
```

Second, if you want only the max time for some group -- say based on the column `result` -- then modify this to be a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM measrate m
WHERE TRANS_TIME = (SELECT MAX(TRANS_TIME) FROM measrate m2 WHERE m2.result= m.result);
```